# Browsers incorrectly flag my intranet sites as phishing

Tags: firefox, browser, intranet, phishing

I have several (not only) web services running on my local network, like TrueNas, jellyfin, pihole, home assistant, etc.

Some are accessible from outside (I have a static public IP and port forwarding is set up). I also have DNS (several subdomains, like pihole.xxxx.xx pointing to my public IP) and HTTPS certificates set up for access.

At the same time, I also set up DNS, which runs locally, so that when someone tries to access the services from the LAN, the domain name is translated directly to the local IP (in my case 192.168.7.X), and that the services can be accessed by domain name even in the event of an Internet outage.

The problem is that with this setting, browsers (chrome and Firefox) consider the sites to be phishing. I assume that because the translated IP (192.168.7.X) doesn't match the one it knows about (my public IP), it thinks the page has been spoofed.

I want to find a way to get rid of this warning.

Ideally by some configuration change on the network (so that I don't have to configure each client browser) that would ensure the same access but wouldn't be considered problematic.

But if there is no such solution, I will also configure each client.

The only solution I have found so far is to disable protection in the browser completely, but I don't want to do that in the long term.

I'm also tried to report the incorrect alert to Google, but with no feedback.

Comment: Can you include a shot of the error warning?  I'm not sure I agree with "I assume that because the translated IP (192.168.7.X) doesn't match the one it knows about (my public IP), it thinks the page has been spoofed" it would be folly to think DNS response enumerated all IP addresses exhaustively

Comment: erik258, You're right that it doesn't quite make sense.

But on the other hand, something had to trigger google to think that the page is phishing.

And since this is a domain which at this moment only I know and use and the pages do not contain anything that would like to look like another website (unless we count that e.g. "my" pihole looks the same as "another" pihole, since it is it's the same self-hosted application) the only thing that I thought could look suspicious are the different IPs at the local DNS.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how  add a screeshot here (it would be in Slovak anyway) - if you need to see it, just search Google for "Deceptive site ahead" images.